# Use Nivo graph lib in a single HTML page (React)

Tags: html, reactjs, charts, static

I have a single HTML page with React (**build manually without ANY tools**, just a text editor).
This page is working correctly. Now, I would like to add a PIE Chart with NIVO lib.

When I add the script (CDN) I got the following error in console:

```
exports is not defined
```

I can solve this by creating a fake `exports var = {}` (is that a good solution ?)

But then I have a new error:

```
require is not defined
```

Do that means the CDN link from NIVO is incorrect ? How to solve this ?

**Alternative:** I am open to use another lib working with React. But I want to only use CDN links and a text editor to achieve that.

Full HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Batch stats</title>
    <script>let exports = {};</script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@nivo/pie@0.61.1/dist/nivo-pie.cjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    function Page(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <div>How to add a PIEChart ?</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<Page version="v3"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nivo do not support it.

> you should use the UMD build, however, you'll need a bunch of extra
> dependencies, including D3 packages which are using modern JS
> features.

https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/959